# Cast expression to @Nonnull to avoid warning in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am experimenting with using javax.annotation.{Nonnull,Nullable} to see if it can enhance code quality in Eclipse.  It seems to help in simple cases, but there are cases where it gets awkward, and I want to determine the best strategies for mitigating the problems.

I'm currently looking at a method that looks somewhat like this:

```
public @Nonnull List<Thing> produceSomeThings(Stuff stuff) {
    List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<>();
    if (stuff != null) {
        if (stuff.checkStuff())
            things.add(stuff.getThings());
        }
    }
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(things)) {
        return things.stream() // this line
            .filter(Util.filter(thing -> thing.isBad())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    return things;
}
```

In Eclipse, this presents a warning on "this line", saying this:

```
Null type safety: The expression of type 'List<Thing>' needs unchecked conversion to conform to '@NonNull List<Thing>'
```

I noticed the following Eclipse bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501464 .

This appears to have been fixed, and the fix was available many versions ago.  However, I'm unable to figure out any way to cast this so that it even works, much less doesn't look nasty.

I also tried changing that line to simply assign to "things", but that just moves what line the warning appears at.

What are reasonable options here?

**Update**:

Examining some of the options that @howlger provides, I did the following:

- Modified the libraries/java/java/util/streams/Collectors.eea file, adding the one "1" character suggested
- Implemented the intermediate "toList" functor as suggested

From what I can see, these changes didn't make any difference.  The error message is technically different, but I think it's the same problem.  Adding the "SuppressWarnings" annotation had no effect at all.

The new code (a little closer to the actual real code) is this:

```
Collector<Thing, ?, @NonNull List<Thing>> toList = Collectors.toList();
return orderThing.stream()
        .filter(CartUtil.distinctByKey(individualThing -> individualThing.get_ThingId()))
        .collect(toList);
```

The "toList" expression has this warning:

> Null type safety (type annotations): The expression of type 'Collector<@NonNull Thing,capture#of ?,@NonNull List<@NonNull Thing>>' needs unchecked conversion to conform to '@NonNull Collector<? super @NonNull Thing,capture#of ?,@NonNull List<@NonNull Thing>>'

Comment: My answer shows two alternative solutions. Mixing it up the way you did does not work. Look at the warning message: when mixing it (which by the way does not make sense) it's `@NonNull Collector<Thing, ?, @NonNull List<Thing>> toList = Collectors.toList();` (since Collectors.eea says `Collectors.toList()` never ever returns `null`). Try to replace the second `@NonNull` with  `@Nullable` and you will get an error, since it conflicts with what Collectors.eea says. Before you try any further modifications, tell what result do you get without EAA and with `@SuppressWarnings("null")` for `toList`?

Comment: I'm a bit late, but still let me ask: what kind of `@NonNull` annotation are you using? Seeing mention of `javax.annotation` (which is not standardized, right?) I'm afraid you might still be using declaration annotations, whereas null analysis is **much** more powerful when using annotations declared with `@Target(TYPE_USE)`, particular when used in the context of streams and lambdas which __heavily__ rely on magic generics. Generics are just out of reach for declaration annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Here, not the modified `things` list, but a new object intance of type `List<Thing>`, that was computed based on `things` is returned. Whether this computed list is guaranteed to be non-`null`, depends on what `collect(...)` returns, which depends on the implementation of `Collector`. Since the API does not guarantee it and it is not trivial to deduce from the code, the warning is displayed.

Rewrite your code as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
Collector<Thing, ?, @NonNull List<Thing>> toList = Collectors.toList();
return things.stream()
             .filter(Util.filter(thing -> thing.isBad()))
             .collect(toList);
```

Alternatively, [external null annotations](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_external_null_annotations.htm) should also work if they cover everything used.

Comment: This is the first I've explored external annotations. I've found some resources, like https://github.com/lastnpe/eclipse-null-eea-augments . I tried adding "./libraries/java/java/util/stream" from that project to the external annotations for rt.jar in the JVM compiling this code. That didn't have any effect. It's not at all clear what I have to do for this.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr This does not work because it is incomplete: [nothing for collect() here](https://github.com/lastnpe/eclipse-null-eea-augments/blob/master/libraries/java/java/util/stream/Stream.eea). Does the code snippet of my answer work?

Comment: Why is "collect()" not there? Is it just an oversight, or is there a technical reason why it can't be covered?  I didn't try your code snippet, because even if it works, I don't want to use it. I'm considering introducing this to be used by a large group of mostly inexperienced developers. If we have to add a cast like that anywhere, I will abort this.

Comment: And because I asked about this in the project itself, the omission of "collect()" has supposedly been resolved now.  Unfortunately, it seems to have made no difference. I pulled the new changes, forced a clean, and the warning is still there.

Comment: These EEA files seems not correct to me: `Collectors.toList()` never returns `null` so in Collectors.eea it has to be `<T:Ljava/lang/Object;>()L1java/util/stream/Collector<TT;*L1java/util/List<TT;>;>;`. With this correction it works for me. Make also sure, to specify the correct EAA folder, so it contains `java/util/stream/Collectors.eea`. By the way, I also disagree that `collect(...)` cannot return `null`; it is possible to implement `Collector<T, A, @Nullable R>` and use it in `collect(...)`.

Comment: Several points: I can't tell from this what line in Stream.eea I would replace with this. If you believe the recent change was done wrong, it would make sense for you to respond in the project to the issue that resulted in that change. On your last point, if that's correct, doesn't that invalidate all of this? I still haven't read enough documentation to be able to parse (or even produce) what is in these files).

Comment: By replacing [this line](https://github.com/lastnpe/eclipse-null-eea-augments/blob/master/libraries/java/java/util/stream/Collectors.eea#L7) as mentioned it works for me (independent of my last point, which shows how difficult and error-prone this is). Using EEA means refining the API of others. I recommend to focus on your code and change the code on your side. There might be cases where EEA does not work.

Comment: Hmm, that isn't really working for me. I'll update the post with what I did.

Comment: I've been really struggling trying to get external annotations for the JDK working inside of Eclipse — the documentation has seemed incomplete / incorrect. Can either of you offer any insight? Is this topic perhaps worth a post of its own?